# How can I have my Ubuntu PC (13.10) connect to a Xbox 360 Kinect?

Tags: 13.10, compatibility, xbox-360, kinect

How can I have my Xbox 360 Kinect be registered as a device to my computer? I don't just want to be able to use it as a webcam, although that is still helpful. Is there any software for Ubuntu that allows me to make use of Kinect while still keeping its 3D capabilities?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this yet: [Kinect 3D Video Capture Project](http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/Kinect/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect ?
make sure to read README.md and also check this one out : https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/348

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.